# Reactjs styled-components with typescript props issue applying on all same component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

i am using styled-components with typescript i have problem of sending props below is the code . Problem is i want to use same component and want for example second component margin-top but its applying on both components .Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5zOJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cdw6.png)

Comment: Buddy, It would be really helpful for anyone to help you in case if you have added a code and a working example anywhere like codesandbox.

Comment: buddy i was getting error of coding idententaion while posting question thats why i upload images ( i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Hey, no problem. Is it possible to create the same example on codesandbox. I would like to help you but it's really hard to write the code from the image.